# Current Location Permission Alertview not Shown after giving Dont Allow

Tags: iphone, permissions, gps, uialertview, core-location

I have used CLLocation Manager in my App.
When the App is first Installed It shows me a alerView "Would you like to use your current Location" with Dont Allow and OK option.

But if i select Dont Allow. and next time i am entering my App does not prompt me the Alertview Again.

I am having iPad with iOS 4.3

But After reseting the Locating service in settings it is prompting the Alertview.

Comment: This is in-fact the desired behaviour, as designed by Apple. What were you expecting?

Comment: I want the Alertview to be shown even i select Dont Allow option in the Alertview. Till i accept OK the Alertview should be shown. What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. The device will remember the permission and it is up to the user to manage it in the settings.

Equally, your application can determine that the location has been denied and take appropriate action to prompt the user.

In iOS4.2 and above you can use;

```
+ (CLAuthorizationStatus)authorizationStatus
```

There is also (from iOS4.0)

```
+ (BOOL)locationServicesEnabled
```

Which although not the same, can also be used to provide information to the user.

In earlier versions the [CLLocationManager delegate will be notified of the user denial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CLLocationManagerDelegate) and  so you can take appropriate action. See the section about kCLErrorDenied.

As ever, [copious Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125) here.